# add_feed failed to open stream

Tags: include, feed

Trying to add a new feed with:

```
function events_feed() {
include(TEMPLATEPATH . '/events.php/');
}
add_feed('gpevent','events_feed');
```

And I'm getting  a  failed to open stream directory not found error.

1.events.php lives in the root of my theme folder.

2.I added the function to my functions.php file. Saved & uploaded.

3.Resaved permalinks.

4.Visited `http://example.com/feed/gpevents`

Answer (score 1):

Remove the last `/` in

```
include(TEMPLATEPATH . '/events.php/');
```

If you cannot find a file, check with [file_exists( $path )](http://www.php.net/file-exists) first.

Also `TEMPLATEPATH` is deprecated now, use [`get_stylesheet_directory()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_stylesheet_directory) instead.

And your feed is located at `/gpevent', not`/gpevents' as Stephen Harris noted.

Comment: Looks like a missing 's' from gpevent too

Comment: Oddly, it passes file_exists() but yet I still get a open stream directory not found error.

The feed adress was merely a typo on my behalf. It all works fine locally. I'm baffled.